# Javascript Regex Match the first the occurrence

Tags: javascript, regex

I've this regex (which doesn't do what i want): `/^.*\/(eu|es)(?:\/)?([^#]*).*/` which actually is the js version of: `/^.*/(eu|es)(?:/)?([^#]*).*/`

Well, it doesn't do what i want, of course it works. :) Given this URLs:

- http://localhost/es -> [1] = es, [2] = ''
- http://localhost/eu/bla/bla#wop -> [1] = eu, [2] = 'bla/bla'
- http://localhost/eu/bla/eubla -> [1] = eu, [2] = 'bla'

The first two urls work as i expected. The third one is not doing what i want. As "eu" is found later on the url, it does the match with the second eu instead of the first one. So I would like it to match this: [1] = 'eu', [2] = 'bla/eubla'

How must I do it?

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make the first `*` ungreedy

```
/^.\*?\/(eu|es)(?:\/)?([^#]\*).\*/
```

Btw, do you really need to escape `*` in javascript? Won't this work?

```
/^.*?\/(eu|es)(?:\/)?([^#]*).*/
```

Comment: Fixed. They were no intended to be there, it's just been a confusion that I had with editor preview.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is nongreedy repetition for the first repetition character `*`. Try this:

```
/^.\*?\/(eu|es)(?:\/)?([^#]\*).\*/
```

The only difference is the question mark `?` after the first `*`. If this is missing, the `*` will match as many characters as possible, leading to the undesired behaviour in your third example.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers re the greedy versus non-greedy are fine, but why bother matching the start of the URL anyway?  Just start your expression with:

```
/\/(eu|es)
```

and it will match the first one found on the line.

Comment: True, this also works. Anyway, it's nice to know the ungreedy thing. Thanks to all. :)